# Allow plugins loaded with dlopen() to dynamically link to shared objects in their own directory

Tags: linker, ld, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have an application that loads plugins with `dlopen()`.
The plugins themselves might need to dynamically link to another library (say `libwhatever.so`) which is distributed in their own plugin folder.
The plugin paths are not known to the application or plugin until runtime.

#### Attempts

1) Link plugins with `-Wl,-rpath,.`
This doesn't work because `.` refers to the application directory, not the plugin directory.
It would need to use `-Wl,-rpath,relative/path/to/plugin`, but this relative path is not known to the plugin at compile time.

2) Use `setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", pluginPath, 1)` before `dlopen()` in the application.
This doesn't work because ld.so caches `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before the application starts and doesn't pay attention to the environment variable during runtime.
Maybe there's a way a refresh this cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
```

(Note: single-quote it -- you don't want shell to be expanding it).

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

```
  $ORIGIN (or equivalently ${ORIGIN})
      This expands to the directory containing the program or shared
      object.
```

Comment: This appear to be what I need. I tested $ORIGIN earlier but somehow incorrectly concluded that it was identical to `-rpath=.` It does in fact mean "directory of shared object".

Comment: @Vortico When you tested it earlier, did you single-quote it?

Comment: Yes. There were perhaps other red herrings that prevented the shared object from being loaded.